# Prove, for an open $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x\in \Omega$, that $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega-\{x\})\implies u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega).$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $n\geq 2$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $x\in \Omega$ and $p\geq1$ I want to prove the above implication. We just need to show that the weak derivative of $u$ on the punctured domain remains the weak derivative on $\Omega$. I am unsure of how to do this though. I was thinking we could take a function $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with $x\in supp(\phi)$ and define a new sequence of functions by smoothly cutting $\phi$ off in a ball of decreasing radius around $x$ and then pass to the limit in the definition. However we need $L^1$ convergence of the derivatives but I think this fails.

Comment: Are you aware of the "AC on lines" characterization of Sobolev spaces?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Absolute continuity? I am aware there is some link but not in any kind of detail, where can I read about this? Thanks

Comment: You could look at e.g. Evans and Gariepy "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions"